# Handling scenario by applying best use of OOPS

Tags: c#, oop

In my scenario I have two tables, say employees and managers. And using the first approach.

Below are Employee and Manager classes represent Employees and Managers table object.

```
public abstract class BaseEmployee
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }     
}

[Table("Employees", Schema = "EmployeeData")]
public partial class Employee: BaseEmployee
{

}

 [Table("Managers", Schema = "EmployeeData")]
public partial class Manager: BaseEmployee
{
    [Column("ManagerId")]
    public override long EmployeeId { get; set; }

}
}
```

Below is the code snippet; I am using to save record in Employees and Managers table based on whether the employee is manager or not.

```
BaseEmployee employeeRow;
if (IsManager)
{
     Manager= new Manager();
}
else
{
    employeeRow= new Employee();
}
//Do some stuff
if (IsManager)
{
    context.Managers.Add(employeeRow as Manager);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
else
{
    context.Employees.Add(employeeRow as Employee);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Till here it works fine. Now I want to save Manager in both the tables i.e. Manager and Employee tables.

and want to do something like below:

```
if (IsManager)
{
    context.Managers.Add(employeeRow as Manager);
    context.Employees.Add(employeeRow as Employees);  // throw errors
    context.SaveChanges();
}
else
{
  context.Managers.Add(employeeRow as Employee);
  context.SaveChanges();
}
```

But here it is throwing exception when casting employeeRow to Employees which is obvious as we are instantiating employeeRow with the Manager class in case of  manager. I can handle this situation by creating one more object of type Employee in parallel to Manager object but this doesn't seem right approach to me.

Could anyone please suggest how I could do best use of OOPS to handle this scenario?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you could change the `DbSet` to be of type `BaseEmployee` instead of `Employees`?

Comment: Or possibly make `Manager` inherit from `Employee` rather than `BaseEmployee`.

Comment: Thanks Jurgen for the response. I tried to inherit Manager from Employee but its not saving record in employees tables though getting saved in Managers table.

Comment: It seems its due to table and schema attributes applied on Employee and Manager table... Any suggestion to handle this scenario.